# copy multi rows from another table and insert that rows value to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wonder, if there a way to capture data from multi rows from table, and copy that rows to another table.example table cart, i want capture their value from Cartid column and copy to

[image]

order table
...
[image]

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["email"].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        int count = int.Parse(Session["cartrows"].ToString());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Object objcartid = dt.Rows[0]["cartid"];


        }
```

this what i do to capture Cartid from cart table.
i loss here.

Comment: how about ordered, name, address ect? or do you only want cartids?

Comment: Why the ASP.NET tag for an ADO.NET/SQL question? Why not use `INSERT INTO Table2 (...) SELECT .... FROM Table1 where email=@email` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataTable.Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone?view=netframework-4.7.2)

But if you want only specific columns then you can try something like below (Considering order DataTable will be empty at first)

```
for(var i = 0; i < cart.Rows.Length; i++)
{
   var cartId = cart.Rows[i]["cartid"]

   DataRow row = order.NewRow();
   row["cartid"] = cartId;
   order.Rows.Add(row);
}
```